Android dependency not issue in Flutter Plugin
I am creating a flutter pluggin for a native sdk.
So I added the android dependency in the plugin/android/build.gradle file like this
android {
    if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
        namespace = "com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx_sdk"
    }

    compileSdk = 34

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
        testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:5.0.0")

        implementation 'com.xxxxxx:xxxxx-xxx:x.x.x' // The dependency
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            testLogging {
               events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
               outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
               showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
    }
}

but not able to build when I tried to access the added dependency,

Can you clarify what not being able to access the dependency means? Does the gradle sync pass? When you build the application, does the build pass?

I was able to solve this issue by opening the example/android folder in the Android Studio

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

If you're having trouble building and accessing the dependency in your Flutter plugin project, here are some steps that could help:
1- Double-check Dependency Inclusion: Ensure the dependency's group:artifact:version string is correct. Any typo here would cause build issues.
2- Build and Sync Gradle Files: Sometimes, simply syncing and rebuilding can solve issues with using android studio

Run flutter clean in the project root.
Go to the Android directory in    your plugin project and run
./gradlew clean followed by ./gradlew    build.

3- Dependency Scope: Ensure that your dependency is being imported in the correct scope in your plugin code. You may need to import the SDK in the plugin’s main class, typically located under android/src/main/kotlin.
4- Ensure Compatibility: Make sure that the dependency is compatible with the SDK version and min SDK version in your build.gradle.
5- Examine Build Output: Sometimes, the error messages in the build output provide clues. Check for specific error lines indicating missing classes, incompatible Java versions, or build process issues.
